# Can I easily derive RMSE from gam library test and train in R?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model

I am doing model assessment and comparing models using RMSE. 
How can I easily get to RMSE to plot comparison in gam library or is this not possible?

in train I am using:

```
gam.m9=gam(Y~s(x1,6)+s(x2,5),data=train)
```

and prediction

```
p.m9=predict(gam.m9,newdata=test)
```

Answer (score 3):

As `gam` doesn't provide response residuals (I'm not 100% sure what is in the `$residuals` component of the model fit), I would just do this by hand and compute the model errors from the training observations and the predicted values.

```
rmse <- sqrt(mean((train$Y - p.m9)^2))
```

this will of course be biased as we're evaluating it using the same data to both fit and test the model.

The **caret** package provides functionality to perform other types of training and crossvalidated RMSE using GAMs from the **gam** package. For example by training your model using `method = 'gamSpline'` to use the same splines as you used to fit your model.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did ie calculated by hand. It's not a big deal, but I wanted to know if there is an easier way to call it.